# How to disable login authentication from infinispan sever in docker container

Tags: docker, authentication, dockerfile, infinispan, disable

I **do not want login authentication** to my infinispan server started in docker container

We have done following things to create infinispan sever

1. Take Infinispan official base image (**infinispan/server:10.1.8.Final**)  to create Infinispan server.
2. During Infinispan server creation we need to copy following two files in the container.

   ```
   cache.xml to /data/sk/server/infinispan-server-10.1.8.Final/server/data

   infinispan.xml to /data/sk/server/infinispan-server-10.1.8.Final/server/conf
   ```
3. cache.xml  copied successfully and its content is well reflecting on Infinspan server UI.
4. infinispan.xml  does not persistent.
5. During container creation, infinispan.xml (our file ) is override by the same file which is present in the base image.

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy your configuration to a different directory and pass it as an argument when starting the server. Details in [Infinipan Images repository](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan-images#server-configuration).

ps. not sure if it works in such an old image.

Comment: Instead of volume mounting, we copied myinfinispan.xml  with the authentication code commented. And execute the below command.

$ docker run --name InfiniSpaneServer -p 11222:11222 -d digite/infinispan:0.3 -c "/opt/infinispan/server/conf/myinfinispan.xml"

But getting the following error.
30672a0084cb525530b94a2f3e358f2e73ccb9dadbd780843cadb1473574a702
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"-c\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.

Is there any other way to execute this?